# spotify login problems using flask and spotipy

Tags: python, flask, cookies, spotify, spotipy

I am creating a simple website where users can log in via spotify to create playlist on the basis of tempo.In order log in user via spotify i use the following code.I am using flask and spotipy.

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, session, redirect , render_template
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import secrets
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(24)
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'MUSIC-MATE-COOKIES'
TOKEN_INFO = "token_info"

def get_token():
    token_info = session.get(TOKEN_INFO, None)
    if not token_info:
        raise "exception"
    now = int(time.time())
    is_Expired = token_info['expires_at'] - now < 60
    if (is_Expired):
        sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
        token_info = sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(token_info['refresh_token'])
    return token_info

def create_spotify_oauth():
    return SpotifyOAuth(
        client_id=[Client id],
        client_secret=[client secret],
        redirect_uri=url_for('redirectPage' , _external=True),
        scope=['user-library-read' , 'playlist-read-private' , 'user-library-read' , 'user-top-read' , 'user-follow-read' , 'user-read-private' , 'user-read-email' , 'playlist-modify-public' , 'playlist-modify-private']
    )

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    sp_outh = create_spotify_oauth()
    auth_url = sp_outh.get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/redirect')
def redirectPage():
    sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
    session[TOKEN_INFO]=token_info
    return redirect(url_for('getTracks' , _external=True))

@app.route('/home')
def getTracks():
    try:
        token_info = get_token()
    except:
        return redirect(url_for('login' , _external=False))
    
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token_info['access_token'])
    
    playlists = sp.current_user_playlists(limit=6 , offset=0)['items']
    albums = (sp.current_user_saved_albums(limit=6 , offset=0)['items'])
    artists = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=6 , offset=0)['items']
    return render_template('playlist_page.html' , playlists = playlists , albums = albums , artists=artists )
```

it works fine for the first user.However if anybody else tries to log in the data of first user is shown . I looked everywhere and the problem seems to be that the token of the first user is cached but solution are very advance level and i am a beginner.Is there any way i can modify this code to avoid this problem as the rest of the website is working flawlessly and is nearly completed so i don't want to scrap this.Any suggestion or solution will be really helpful.